# MacBook Pro - Configure trackpad navigation on Blender 2.77 as it worked on 2.76

Tags: interface

I installed a new version of Blender on my MacBook Pro (10.6.8) and have some trouble with trackpad navigation.

On Blender v2.77 (and later) two finger dragging across the trackpad no longer orbits the model like it still did in v2.76. I tried loading the older keymap in the new version, which however didn't restore the behavior.

How do I configure two finger trackpad orbiting in Blender versions 2.77 and later?

Comment: Try File > User Preferences > Input > Emulate 3 Button Mouse.

Comment: Thx legoparrot, but that didn't fix it.